# Java parsing alternative to current solution

Tags: java

I have a text file to parse, that requires different logic depending on certain conditions. Below, is my current solution that works. However, I find it very clunky, and have been looking into other solutions such as StringTokenizer or Pattern class and am wondering I may be able to implement this more elegantly using them.

Do let me know if I should move this to the Code Review forum--I have not initially put it there, as I am unable to implement the other mentioned solutions.

```
    File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    java.io.BufferedReader reader = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader(file));

    memoryMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    registerMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    String line = reader.readLine();
    while (line != null) {

        if (line.contains("#")) {
            System.out.println(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }

        if (!Character.isDigit(line.charAt(0))) {
            System.out.println(line);
            String[] setFirstSplit = line.split(":");
            if (setFirstSplit[0].equals("M")) {
                boolean isFirst = true;
                for (String setFirstSegment : setFirstSplit) {
                    if (!isFirst) {
                        String[] setSecondSplit = setFirstSegment.split(",");
                        for (String setSecondSegment : setSecondSplit) {
                            String[] setThirdSplit = setSecondSegment.split("=");
                            for (String setThirdSegment : setThirdSplit) {
                                System.out.println(setThirdSegment);
                                memoryMap.put(Integer.parseInt(setThirdSplit[0]), Integer.parseInt(setThirdSplit[1]));
                                System.out.println("Memory Set Result: " + memoryMap);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        isFirst = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (setFirstSplit[0].equals("R")) {
                boolean isFirst = true;
                for (String setFirstSegment : setFirstSplit) {
                    if (!isFirst) {
                        String[] setSecondSplit = setFirstSegment.split(",");
                        for (String setSecondSegment : setSecondSplit) {
                            String[] setThirdSplit = setSecondSegment.split("=");
                            for (String setThirdSegment : setThirdSplit) {
                                System.out.println(setThirdSegment);
                                registerMap.put(Integer.parseInt(setThirdSplit[0]), Integer.parseInt(setThirdSplit[1]));
                                System.out.println("Register Set Result: " + registerMap);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        isFirst = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            line = reader.readLine();
        } else {
            System.out.println(line);
            String[] actionFirstSplit = line.split(" ");
            if (actionFirstSplit[1].equals("LOAD")) {
                String[] actionSecondSplit = actionFirstSplit[2].split(",");
                LoadStep action = new LoadStep();
                action.executeStep(Integer.parseInt(actionSecondSplit[0]), Integer.parseInt(actionSecondSplit[1]));
                System.out.println("Memory Action Result: " + memoryMap);
                System.out.println("Register Action Result: " + registerMap);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
    }
    reader.close();
```

The text file looks like this:

```
# sets the memory address 0 to store the value 1. M stands for memory.
M:0=1,1=11
# All programs starts with an initial setup of values in memory such as the example shown above
0 LOAD 1,3
1 LOAD 0,2
2 ADD 1,2
3 ADD 0,1
4 LSS 1,3,2
5 STOR 62,1
6 STOP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write it top-down.

```
String line = reader.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    if (parsedComment(line)) {
    } else if (parsedMemory(line)) {
    } else if (parsedInstruction(line)) {
    } else {
         error(...);
    }
    line = reader.readLine();
}
```

Parse functions may use fields to pass results, like those maps, or have extra parameters.

(If you have multi-line syntax, the reader might be better placed in a field, and disappear as parameter. You can then read a line ahead in the field, and check on that.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a parser generator like ANTLR http://www.antlr.org/